# Log em arquivos separados com SLF4J na AWS

Tags: amazon-aws, log, slf4j

Alguém já implementou log utilizando **SLF4J** para possibilitar que a aplicação separe os arquivos por *tenant* em ambiente Amazon?

Fiz essa implementação na minha aplicação, no *tomcat* rodando local os arquivos de log são gerados normalmente, porém quando faço o deploy na Amazon e posteriormente faço o download dos logs, os arquivos não são gerados, as saídas acabam indo para o `catalina.out`.

Comment: Que tipo de deploy você faz: direto em EC2? Elastic Beanstalk? CloudFormation? A maioria dos meus problemas com logs residem em caminhos inexistentes ou falta de permissão de acesso.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema definindo o caminho que condiz com a estrutura que os logs são armazenados no tomcat da Amazon.

Fiz a seguinte alteração no arquivo de configuração do meu filter.

```
<File>/var/log/tomcat8/nomedoarquivo.log</File>
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Localmente você deve ter configurações que precisam ser feitas no tomcat, como jars no classpath e parâmetros da JVM, que podem ser configurados pelos arquivos .ebextensions/*.config do Elastic Beanstalk, veja mais em http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Comment: Vou tentar verificar se eu necessito de alguma configuração adicional, porém eu estou achando que minha aplicação não está conseguindo gravar outros arquivos de log por não encontrar a estrutura de pastas semelhante a local do tomcat, por exemplo na minha máquina local configuro para que os arquivos fiquem em ../logs/nomedoarquivo.log, porém ao fazer o download dos log na Amazon não vem nessa estrutura, a pasta descompactada é var/log/tomcat8/...

Comment: Sim, isso depende se voce instala pelo .rpm (eb) ou o .zip (vc)... que bom que encontraste o problema.

Comment: Sim, de qualquer forma agradeço a atenção.  :D